# Address Book Retrieving Mobile, Work, and iPhone phone numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abpeoplepickerview

I started developing a settings page for my app.

On this page, the user can tap a **"+"** button which will open the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`. When the contact is tapped, the text fields on the settings page will be filled appropriately with the correct data from the chosen user.

I understand that if I want to retrieve someone's work email, it's:

```
NSString *workEmail = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 1);
```

and for home it would be:

```
NSString *homeEmail = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
```

But as far as retrieving different types of phone numbers, I am stuck.

I would appreciate it much if someone could tell me how to get the different types of phone numbers hopefully similar to the way I get the two emails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first off, you understand wrong--there's no guarantee that the user's home email address is #0. What if you *only* have that user's work email? Then *that* will be in slot 0.

What you want is `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex()`, which when used with named constants will tell you which is which:

```
ABPersonRef person = ...;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (phoneNumbers) {
    CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
        CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
        if (label) {
            if (CFEqual(label, kABWorkLabel)) {
                /* it's the user's work phone */
            } else if (CFEqual(label, kABHomeLabel)) {
                /* it's the user's home phone */
            } else if (...) {
                /* other specific cases of your choosing... */
            } else {
                /* it's some other label, such as a custom label */
            }
            CFRelease(label);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
}
```

Comment: So inside the "if() brackets" I would put "self.workTextField.text = (__bridge NSString *)(kABWorkLabel); Is that correct?

Comment: If you want to display an unlocalized string representing the "work" label, then yes. This is probably not what you want to do though.

Comment: Say i have a textfield that only wants to pick up the work email ONLY.

Comment: So you want to display the *value* of the email address, right?

Comment: Yes, yes. email or phone. I'd like to pick up the value and display it in the textfield.

Comment: Then the body of the `if` statement would be something like `NSString *thePhoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i)); self.workTextField.text = thePhoneNumber;` Though this is getting away from your original question, which was how to determine which phone number corresponded to which label.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your previous response was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Next time, I'll be more clear as to what I'm looking for in my questions..